# Is there any method to clear web browser console, every time browser get a response.(without page reloading)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console

Instead of clear the web console output using the inbuilt button or calling `clear()` method of the browser and without reloading the page, is there a way to clear web browser console output (chrome/firefox) when the browser gets a response from backend? So in this case, at a particular time console output is relevant only most recent response. Thank you!

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear) ?

Comment: I get `console.clear() was prevented due to 'Preserve log'`

Comment: I'm wondering, why are you saying This question already has answers here. At least you read my question? My question Is different from it.

Comment: No it is not. `function loadData() { console.clear(); getData() }`

Comment: Thank you. I'm newbie to SO. extremely sorry. I will refer it